# Moving from jboss 3.2.1 to jboss6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-2.x

Now we have a project with java 1.4 and ejb 2.1 running on jboss 3.2.1. We are trying to update up to java 6 and ejb3.1, but we are doing it in steps. So my question is simple, can we use ejb2.1 on jboss6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, yes. EJB 2.x is still part of the current JavaEE spec, and JBoss6 supports it fully.

However, JBossAS 3.x and 6.x are architecturally very different to each other. Do not assume the upgrade will be a smooth one, it may well feel like migrating to a completely new appserver.